# No static method intArrayOf how to solve the problem?

Tags: android, kotlin

The application crashes when I use the **intArrayOf** method.

How do I fix the code in this section? ↓

```
companion object {
    private val STATE_ERROR = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_error)

    const val ACTION_NONE = 0
    const val ACTION_CANCEL = 1
    const val ACTION_HINT = 2
}
```

This is how I solved the error in another document below. But how do I fix this error?

```
private fun initChart() {
    val numbers = IntArray(5) { 10 * (it + 1) }
    chartUpload.init(numbers)
    val download = IntArray(5) { 10 * (it + 1) }
    chartDownload.init(download)
    //chartUpload.init(intArrayOf(5, 30, 100, 65, 80))
    //chartDownload.init(intArrayOf(5, 30, 65, 50, 100))
}
```

This problem was solved with the IntArray method. ↑

Error Log

```
12-08 16:43:22.143 11878-11878/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 11878
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method intArrayOf([I)[I in class Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics$Kotlin; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics$Kotlin' appears in /data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk:classes4.dex)
        at app.witwork.vpn.common.widget.InputView.<clinit>(InputView.kt:21)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at app.witwork.vpn.common.base.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2290)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5307)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Have you tried this on unobfuscated version?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I do not fully understand what you said? :)

Comment: @augur Hello, I edited the topic. I shared the log message on the subject

Comment: Is 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib' added to dependecies? According to error, the method is not visible

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be related to your system language. There is a problem with the small "i" letter in kotlin. Either change the system language to English or use alternatives such as IntArray.